# Flex - invisible text until mouse pointer moves outside textInput

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, flash, textinput, citrix

We have an application running flex sdk 4.5 and have recently encountered an issue with textInput fields which we have not been able to reproduce on our end for the better part of a month now.

Here are the symptoms:

- Users opens an input form which contains several input fields (combo boxes, calendars, text inputs, etc)
- User clicks inside a text field
- Users types (obviously!)
  ** Nothing appears in the text input - we have validators on some of these fields and they do kick in properly (ie. user sees red box around textInput disappearing)
- User moves cursor outside of text input field and text appears

Give or take, this is the test case we've been provided. We have been unable to reproduce this and I'm reaching out to see if anybody has heard of issues like this in the past.

They are running our flex application in the following environment:
Windows XP SP3
IE 7.0.5730.13 (locale = en-gb)
Flash Player 10.3.181.14

Upgrading either of these components is not an option. Installing the flash player debugger is not an option either.

Now we've setup a pc exactly the same way as they have on their end and still haven't reproduced. So we're really stuck at this point :)

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. I'll provide any additional info needed.

-Marc

Feb. 2nd 2012 - Update

As I noted in my comment reply to shaun, it seems our customer was more or less precise in their description of the issue. We ran a webex session with them this morning and actually saw the issues first hand.

Here's what happens:
- User loads our application via its url
- User is able to input data and pretty much do any function for a 'random' time period
- All of a sudden, the issues start (there are more symptoms than just the one I originally mentioned):
1. Users type in text input fields and they won't see the text appear until they move the cursor out of / into **any other component** (could be entering an hbox, exiting a text input field, etc)
2. Combo boxes behave more or less the same. They can drop them down, but then the mouse wheel no longer refreshes the list. It actually scrolls in the background, but until the user moves the mouse, the list does not refresh
3. We also communicate between the server and client via an amf channel. The events make it to the client, but again, they won't see the screen refresh until they move their cursor.

So basically, the application still seems to work, but the screen is no longer refreshing. Could it be something to do with an invalidate / update of the display list that doesn't kick in? We'd like to get them to install the debugger version of FP, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Another thing to keep in mind: they have a VERY bad internet connection. They average around 1-1.5mbps (megabits) which is enough for our app, but I just thought I'd let you know.

We learned that they also use a Citrix presentation layer to deploy IE 7 to the end users. We've received confirmation from the end user that even if they launch IE on their workstation (not through citrix), they get the issue also.

Another note is that we've seen no errors in our web server, jboss or application logs...

So that's the update I've got... anyone have more thoughts on this? We've more or less discarded the fonts being an issue at this point since the issue affects more than just 'fonts'. Is everything on the screen not updating anymore.

Comment: Anything special that should be known about the styling of the text? CSS embedded fonts anything of that nature?

Comment: Hi Shaun, we've had a bit more feedback from our customer who is experiencing this issue. Basically, when they first load our application, everything runs fine. After what seems like a random period of time (5-10-15 mins or so), the issue begins occurring. So, everything runs fine, they can enter text in the input fields, etc. Then all of a sudden, it all stops working completely. No error message, just that most components start behaving like I described in my question. It almost looks like there's no more updateDisplayList called... at least that's how it feels

Comment: Hi Marc, so from your updates it sounds like your right in your assumption that for some reason the invalidation or updating of the display list is no longer occurring.  My guess is that there is actually a flash error occurring at some point (perhaps a service call that is polling in the background is intermittently failing or something along those lines).  Checking out the logs was a good first step, aside from reproducing with a debug version of the player I'm not sure what else you can really do.  The kind of behavior your describing occurs sometimes after an error has been thrown.

Comment: Hi Shaun, thanks again for the feedback. We're going to push our customer to get the debugger installed. We may try to add some more logging within our application to try and pinpoint the root cause of this...